# Recursive Method that Evaluates a Mathematical Expression from a Queue

Tags: java, recursion, queue

I'm trying to write a recursive function that evaluates a Queue as a mathematical expression. The queue can have any of the following characters: { '(', ')', '+', '*'} or any single-digit number. I want to evaluate this expression and return the result. I can not use any
loops or any data structures besides the q passed in as a parameter. This is what I have but I'm not quite sure why it's not working and I can't figure out how to add recursion.

```
public static int evaluate(Queue<Character> q) {
    if (q.peek().equals("(") || q.peek().equals(")")) {
        q.remove();
    }
    if (!(q.peek().equals("+") || q.peek().equals("*"))) {
        int i = q.poll();
        if (q.poll().equals("+")) {
            int x = q.poll();
            char d = (char)(i+x);
            q.add(d);
        }
        int x;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: anyone need any clarifications

Comment: please produce some examples of the input and the output

Comment: What is that `int x` doing at the end of the block?